# Finding duplicate using Python

Tags: pyqgis, sql

I'm creating a plugin and trying to get the duplicate geometry in my layer and I did it by putting the query in the Python program:

```
query = """
select * from
(select *, count(geometry) as num_geom from "Mainline" group by geometry) as a
where a.num_geom > 1
"""

vlayer = QgsVectorLayer( "?query={}".format(query), "vlayer", "virtual" )
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer)
```

This will create a new layer for the duplicate feature.

Instead, I want a code to print out all the duplicate without creating an additional layer. Will also create a GUI using Qt Designer and put the output on a table. Is there a way to still use the query to do that or do you have some code on how to do this without SQL?

Answer (score 3):

You can try to use the following expression in a virtual field

```
aggregate(
 layer:=@layer,
 aggregate:='count',
 expression:=geom_to_wkt($geometry),
 filter:=geom_to_wkt($geometry) = geom_to_wkt(geometry(@parent))
)
```

Then, duplicates are where the field calculated > 1